# Does roscore on Windows need a rosout.exe in order to run?

Tags: ros, rosout, win-ros, roscore, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I've built win_ros and get the following exes for my Windows machine.
roscore.exe        roscreate-stack.exe  rosmaster.exe  rosservice.exe  rostopic.exe
roscreate-pkg.exe  roslaunch.exe        rospack.exe    rosstack.exe    rosversion.exe
rosxxx.exe

On Windows I set up the env vars and paths following these [guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Tutorials/Mingw%20Runtime%20Environment) but when I run roscore in command prompt it crashes.

I have not yet built rosout.exe and I'm guessing that roscore cannot run without it and this is why it's crashing? Is this correct?
rospack runs fine.
All others crash but that's because roscore is not running. Thanks for any help

Tarik

Update: I built rosout.exe and put it in %ROS_INSTALL_ROOT%/ros/bin with all other exes, roscore still crashes

Update:
I'm on XP and get a "roscore has encountered a problem" popup. If I then click Debug, it says "unhandled win32 exception occurred [192]
Where should I have the roscore.xml file located? It's in %ROS_INSTALL_ROOT%\ros_comm\tools\roslaunch. Do I need to add this to the path?
When running python I get:
C:\ros\ros\bin>python roscore.exe
File "roscore.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file roscore.exe on line 1, but no en
coding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Update: Sorry, think I'm being stupid here, so should I have binaries in the bin folder other than exes? i.e. other cross-compiled binaries? Do I need a python compatible roscore in order to call C:\ros\ros\bin>python roscore ( and not python roscore.exe as I did above?)

Update: I did have other binaries in the bin folder but I thought they were for linux however they may have been written over after building win_ros. So if I run python roscore, I get "ImportError: No module named rosmaster"
If I run python rosmaster --core, it runs and I get a log in my log folder indicating
"[rosmaster.main][INFO] 2011-08-03 15:30:33,171: Starting ROS Master Node
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-08-03 15:30:33,171: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-08-03 15:30:33,171: Started XML-RPC server [http://192.168.134.1:11311/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2011-08-03 15:30:33,171: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server"

However, from another shell if I run python roslaunch, I get the No module name rosmaster error.

I'm wondering what is the problem now and also what is the problem with my exes?

Thanks for any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10803/does-roscore-on-windows-need-a-rosout.exe-in-order-to-run?/) by [Tarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/863/tarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-03**:
You can also run the programs in ros/bin without the exe's. They are just there for convenience. Simply run 'python xxx' (e.g. 'python %ROS_ROOT%/bin/roscore'). That should give you good python traces.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-03**:
You can run roscore without rosout - see http://answers.ros.org/question/1034/roslaunch-without-rosout. That might be worth trying.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-03**:
What kind of messages are you getting in the crashes?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-02**:
I added win_ros to the tags - it's always a good idea to include the stack name so that the right people might get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I think you have run into a bug that I accidentally introduced recently when trying to fix another big (apologies). I just stepped through the process myself again from scratch and found something awry with the PYTHONHOME variables throughout win_ros.

If you want to be sure, start again from scratch and follow the now slightly more verbose [guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Tutorials/Mingw%20Runtime%20Environment).

If you want to just skip to the chase and retry with a minimum of effort, on your linux box

```
> roscd win_ros; svn update
> roscd win_py2exe
> make clean; make
```

This will fix those exe's.

- copy over the exe's in ROS_ROOT/bin from lin to win.
- copy win_env/scripts/winshell.bat -> ROS_ROOT/setup.bat (some changes in here)
- recheck your variables in setup.bat are correct

and you should be able to go. Thanks for identifying this.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0